# Regex: Show everything but single digits

Tags: regex

**Sample text**

> User  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  10000  100007  user.b  user.x  30000  80001
>   user.c

**Desired Output**

> User  10000  100007  user.b  user.x  30000  80001  user.c

**Current Solution**

I can match what I want : `\b\d{1}\b`
The match from that regex is : `1  2  3  4  5  6  7` but the use of `(?!)` fails to ignore the pattern to allow me to get the desired output.

Comment: What do you mean by `(?!)`? Where is it? I believe all you need is `\s*\b\d\b` to use in a regex replace method. What is the environment?

Comment: Your [**regex works**](https://regex101.com/r/hX9gB3/1), just replace this with `''`. Or even better: @WiktorStribiżew's solution: https://regex101.com/r/hX9gB3/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all you need is to replace standalone digits. You have several options:

- Replace using your modified [`\s*\b\d\b`](https://regex101.com/r/bQ8yF2/1) pattern (replacement is an empty string)
- Use a similar regex but grab the digits in one go by wrapping the pattern around with a group and apply `+` quantifier on it: [`(?:\s*\b\d\b)+`](https://regex101.com/r/bQ8yF2/2).

Note that `\d{1}` = `\d` as each non-quantified atom is tried once.

You might want to add `(?<!\S)` lookbehind before `\d` and `(?!\S)` lookahead after `\d` to make sure there are no non-whitespace symbols around the digit, but I suspect they are redundant in this scenario.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/3Wn5Rg):

```
import re
s = "User 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 10000 100007 user.b user.x 30000 80001 user.c"
res = re.sub(r'(?:\s*\b\d\b)+', '', s)
print(res)
# => User 10000 100007 user.b user.x 30000 80001 user.c
```

Comment: Hi Wiktor, well it seems that well it works but not under python regex:
`>>> b = re.findall(r"\s*\b\d\b", a)`


`>>> print b
['  1', '  2', '  3', '  4', '  5', '  6']`

he is selecting the match instead of ignoring or replace it by empty string do you know if sed or egrep do it ?

Comment: @s3gfault: You need to use `re.sub()`

Comment: Aha, so it is Python. Use `re.sub(r'(?:\s*\b\d\b)+', '', s)`